# Export all the response from Chrome Developer to a file

Tags: google-chrome, networking, export

Hello there is a webpage which shows the table. The table has like 200K rows. But the webpage load rows when you scroll down. So as long as you are scrolling new data is coming up. When I checked through the chrome developer tool in the network tab, it is working like it is calling a particular function again and again and getting around 10 rows on each scroll. I need those rows data. So at the moment what I am doing is that 
I scrolled the page, copy one response, paste it into the file and then come again copying the second and so on and it will take a lot of time. 
So I want to know is there any option that I press just scroll and all the data which is coming up would be stored on a separate file and keeps appending the data as long as I scroll

Answer (score 0):

This is old but maybe you are still around.
One thing that you might want to try is copy the request that you are seeing which requests a new set of data, NOT the response.
Paste the request in an text editor where you can see it easily. 
If you can determine what part of the request sets the number of rows desired you can change that value then paste the URL into a blank tab in chrome and it will request the data for you and return it in raw format in that window.
You will need to have an active session in another tab in many cases, but some you can simply bookmark the request and get the data anytime you need if it is something that frquently changes.